# How to alias run twice in mix.exs?

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix

I'm trying to run two different scripts, v1_to_v2_migrator.exs and update_images.exs

```
defp aliases do
  ["ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/v1_to_v2_migrator.exs", "run priv/repo/update_images.exs"]
```

Only the first file runs. I've tried to reenable `run` but I can't escape the filename.

`"run 'priv/repo/v1_to_v2_migrator.exs'; run -e 'Mix.Task.reenable(:run)'"`

gives this error:

`** (Mix) No such file: priv/repo/v1_to_v2_migrator.exs;`

Where the file ending includes the semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your particular example, you can pass multiple files to run:

```
mix run -r priv/repo/foo.exs -r priv/repo/bar.exs
```

But if the question is how to generally reenable tasks, then @Dogbert's and @mudasobwa's approaches are correct.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Mix.Task.rerun/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Task.html#rerun/2) to invoke `mix run` twice like this:

```
["ecto.reset": [
  "ecto.drop",
  "ecto.create",
  "ecto.migrate",
  ~s|run -e 'Mix.Task.rerun("run", ["priv/repo/v1_to_v2_migrator.exs"]); Mix.Task.rerun("run", ["priv/repo/update_images.exs"])'|]]
```

Answer (score 2):

While answer by @Dogbert would work, I’d suggest you take a different approach. When you find yourself stuck with the tool’s provided functionality it usually means the paradigm change is required.

Unlike many other build tools, `mix` welcomes task creation. It’s easy, pretty straightforward and more idiomatic than executing multiple scripts. Just create a file, say, `my_awesome_task.ex` in your `lib/mix/tasks` directory (create the directory unless it already exists,) using the following scaffold:

```rb
defmodule Mix.Tasks.MyAwesomeTask do
  use Mix.Task

  @shortdoc "Migrates v1 to v2 and updates images"

  @doc false
  def run(args \\ []) do
    # it’s better to implement stuff explicitly,
    #   but this is also fine
    Mix.Tasks.Run.run(["priv/repo/v1_to_v2_migrator.exs"])
    Mix.Tasks.Run.rerun(["priv/repo/update_images.exs"])
  end
end
```

Now all you need is to call this task in your `mix.exs`:

```rb
["ecto.reset": ~w|ecto.drop ecto.create ecto.migrate my_awesome_task|]
```